# How to save select dropdown menu option in HTML/pure JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have this code:

```
<select id = dropdown-list>
    <option value = "0"> Yes </option>
    <option value = "1"> No </option>
</select>
```

The user can select yes or no from a dropdown list. How can I use pure JS/HTML to figure out what the user has selected (and is currently showing in the dropdown list box when the list isn't expanded) so I can use that data elsewhere? The only way I can figure out is if I add an eventListener on each option but I feel there is a better way. I am quite new to JS so I'm not sure. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute a JavaScript function `changeResult` when a user changes the selected option of a  element:

Flow:

1. We bind `changeRegult` using `onchange` event listener.
2. When we change the dropdown menu, it calls `changeResult` function.
3. Inside the function, we select our `dropdown menu` using its `id` property.
4. After getting the element by id, we can now access all properties.
5. Here we want to show the value property, so we use `document.getElementById("dropdown-list").value`.

For more check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementbyid2).

```js
function changeResult() {
  var x = document.getElementById("dropdown-list").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
```

```html
<select id = "dropdown-list" onchange="changeResult()">
    <option value = "0"> Yes </option>
    <option value = "1"> No </option>
</select>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onchange` attribute from `select` element.

```html
<select id="dropdown-list" onchange="onChange(this.value)">
    <option value = "0"> Yes </option>
    <option value = "1"> No </option>
</select>
```

and in JS:

```js
function onChange(val) {
  // `val` is the value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use on change event.
Since you use each I suppose you are using Jquery.
If you have any question just let me know.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dropdown-list').on('change',function(){
    alert($(this).children('option:selected').val());
  })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u4dz162o/

Comment: This is for a class assignment where most of the assignment we are essentially learning ourselves, but we're not allowed to use Jquery, react, unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah can be easily done in JS too, can't quite remember the steps though.